# Creating a hash and encrypting/salting it

Tags: php, hash, passwords, openssl

So another stack overflow user recommended the following code to create a hash:

```
$password = 'my password';
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(18)), '+', '.');
$pwhash = crypt($password, sprintf('$2y$%02d$%s', 13, $salt));
```

Is there another function for openssl_random_pseudo_bytes if I don't have openssl installed?  Does it make sense to install this, and if so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mcrypt_create_iv(18)`. Although it is used for generating initialization vectors for encryption it uses `/dev/random` by default for generating a random vector.

EDIT: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will try this in a little bit and get back to you!

Comment: @Kazi Yes!  Thank you so much for your help!  After further digging it looks like my host is using an old version of PHP, which means that I can't use openssl.  Mcrypt is exactly what I was looking for until I switch hosts!

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to create BCrypt hashes (that is what your function does). There is a [compatibility pack](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash) for PHP 5.3/5.4 available, downloadable in form of a single php file [password.php](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php).

It is a well done implementation, that uses mcrypt_create_iv, but has a fallback to openssl_random_pseudo_bytes.

```
mcrypt_create_iv($raw_length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

Note that the mcrypt_create_iv function reads from `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`, that's enough for creating password salts (salt should be unique and unpredictable). In contrast to the default value MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM it does not block the server, should there be not enough entrophy available.